# How to customize the xml format in an xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using the Jaxb Marshaller to convert java object to xml and also setting Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT to true. This is giving me xml in below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml>
    <time>20210716124226</time>
    <details>
        <employee id="100" time="20210716124212">
            <name>asd</name>
            <empid>1</empid>           
            <jobCategory>Contract</jobCategory>            
        </employee>
        <employee id="102" time="20210716124212">
            <name>ative</name>
            <empid>2</empid>            
            <jobCategory>Permanent</jobCategory>                    
        </employee>
    </details>
</xml>
```

But the requirement is to generate the xml in below format with no indentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml>
<time>20210716124226</time>
<details>
<employee id="100" time="20210716124212"><name>xyz</name><empid>1</empid><jobCategory>Contract</jobCategory></employee>
<employee id="102" time="20210716124212"><name>abc</name><empid>2</empid><jobCategory>Permanent</jobCategory></employee>
</details>
</xml>
```

How can i achieve this result using java?

Comment: You can remove the command to format: `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);` this will provide the result as a text rather than the XML with a proper indentation that makes it easier for us to read. If you want to display the XML with exact indentation as you have provided then you have to write custom indentation. But I do not see the need why you don't want to have indentation this will make it easy for you to read right? Also, it's not making any changes to your XML content.

Comment: The problem is that this xml file will be used by client application as an input data source and that application is legacy application which accepts the input xml file format as the format which i have mentioned above in the requirement. Due to compliance and regulatory conditions i don't have access to the client application so i don't really know about the implementation of that and how it works internally. And they are not ready to accept the xml file with the standard/default format and asking me to customize it as per their expectation.

Comment: Show us code you use to write that xml. It looks like you need to put some annotations on your POJO.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty exasperating, the number of times we have to tell people consuming XML to parse it properly, and the number of people who are stuck with the problem of generating XML for people who don't parse it properly. But that's life - people don't realise the value of standards conformance until they are stuck with the task of fitting a round plug into a square hole. To do this, and adapter is needed -- and it's always better to put the adapter on the non-conformant side of the interface, which in this case is the consumer. But there's no telling people.

In this instance, writing the adapter isn't difficult. Both the Xalan and Saxon XML serializers have an option to indent with indent-spaces=0, which should give the format you want, so you just have to put your XML through an identity transformation with this option set.